# GSM ZTE MG2639 module freezes after checking SIM

Tags: communication, uart, gsm, at-commands

I'm communicating with my ZTE MG2639 module through UART. 
Few seconds after powering it and getting `+CPIN` and `+STKPCI` it just turns off (goes to stand by mode)

It only happens with SIM card, and after sending PIN.

What's wrong? I have tried on few different SIM cards and antennas.

Comment: I´m starting to use ZTE MG2639_V3, and I no have problems with serial communications, I have problems to connect GPRS. Your project with MG2639 module is OK ? I would like to share some ideas with you.

Comment: I have found what was my problem. It looks like this module is draining huge current in quick burst and my power supply is to slow for that. I have added 1 cell LiPo and it's working like a charm! Thank you for your answer though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found what was my problem. It looks like this module is draining huge current in quick burst and my power supply is to slow for that. Adding 1 cell LiPo did a trick.